# Perl Date::Parse - how to correctly parse dates between 1901 and 1969

Tags: perl, date, datetime, time

### Background

I am using Perl to parse dates and datetimes input by users who aren't too careful with their formatting. The Perl module `Date::Parse` seems great because it handles most cases I need to handle.

Except datetimes between `1901-01-01 00:00:00` and `1968-12-31 23:59:59`, as I found out today. For those datetimes, Date::Parse str2time adds an extra 100 years when it parses the datetime to epoch time.

### Code

Here is the code I am using to parse the datetimes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# format_date.pl
#
# format variable date inputs
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Parse;
use DateTime;

my $DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = "GMT";

my @dates = (
    "1899-06-24 09:44:00",
    "1900-12-31 23:59:59",
    "1901-01-01 00:00:00",
    "1960-12-31 23:59:59",
    "1966-06-24 09:44:00",
    "1968-12-31 23:59:59",
    "1969-01-01 00:00:00",
    "1969-12-31 23:59:59",
    "1970-01-01 00:00:01",
    "2000-01-01 00:00:00",
    "2017-06-24 23:59:59",
    "2018-06-24 09:44:00",
    "2238-06-24 09:44:00"

);

foreach my $string (@dates) {

    # format datetime field from any valid datetime input
    # default time zone is used if timezone is not included in string
    my $epoch = str2time( $string, $DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE );

    # error if date is not correctly parsed
    if ( !$epoch ) {
        die("ERROR ====> invalid datetime ($string), "
        . "datetime format should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
    }

    my $date = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );

    printf( "formatting datetime: value = %20s, epoch = %20u, "
            . "date = %20s\n", $string, $epoch, $date );

}

exit 0;
```

Side note: I need to improve my error handling because the valid date `1970-01-01 00:00:00` will throw an error.

### Output

The additional 100 years for dates between 1901 and 1969 can be seen in the output:

```
formatting datetime: value =  1899-06-24 09:44:00, epoch = 18446744071484095456, date =  1899-06-24T09:44:00
formatting datetime: value =  1900-12-31 23:59:59, epoch = 18446744071532098815, date =  1900-12-31T23:59:59
formatting datetime: value =  1901-01-01 00:00:00, epoch =            978307200, date =  2001-01-01T00:00:00
formatting datetime: value =  1960-12-31 23:59:59, epoch =           2871763199, date =  2060-12-31T23:59:59
formatting datetime: value =  1966-06-24 09:44:00, epoch =           3044598240, date =  2066-06-24T09:44:00
formatting datetime: value =  1968-12-31 23:59:59, epoch =           3124223999, date =  2068-12-31T23:59:59
formatting datetime: value =  1969-01-01 00:00:00, epoch = 18446744073678015616, date =  1969-01-01T00:00:00
formatting datetime: value =  1969-12-31 23:59:59, epoch = 18446744073709551615, date =  1969-12-31T23:59:59
formatting datetime: value =  1970-01-01 00:00:01, epoch =                    1, date =  1970-01-01T00:00:01
formatting datetime: value =  2000-01-01 00:00:00, epoch =            946684800, date =  2000-01-01T00:00:00
formatting datetime: value =  2017-06-24 23:59:59, epoch =           1498348799, date =  2017-06-24T23:59:59
formatting datetime: value =  2018-06-24 09:44:00, epoch =           1529833440, date =  2018-06-24T09:44:00
formatting datetime: value =  2238-06-24 09:44:00, epoch =           8472332640, date =  2238-06-24T09:44:00
```

### Additional notes

The [`Date::Parse`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm) documentation suggests it can handle dates at least as old at 1901-01-01. The [`Time::Local`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Time-Local-1.25/lib/Time/Local.pm) documentation suggest it should be able handle dates even older.

### Question

How should I handle this oddity? Is there a better way to parse variable input formats suing Perl?

### Edit: examples of multiple date formats

Input can be in multiple formats. Here is an array of examples:

```
my @dates = (
    "2018-02-20 00:00:00",
    "20180220",
    "02/20/2018",
    "02/20/18",    # interpreted as 1918-02-20
    "2018-02-20"
);
```

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1209504).

Comment: _variable input formats_ All your inputs are YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. What am I missing?

Comment: @MattJacob These are test dates. I didn't want to complicate the issue of the epoch time. Actual dates can have variable formats.

Comment: So show at least a good sample of those variable formats.

Comment: The problem is with Date::Parse - see [this issue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=105031). Full answer on [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1209514)

Comment: I have added a sample of the variable formats. I didn't include them initially because I was trying to tease out the problem with the extra 100 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue was answered by tangent.

> The problem is with Date::Parse - see [this issue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=105031). Full answer on [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1209514) – [tangent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190901/tangent)

### Solution 1

My solution is to use Date::Parse strptime instead of str2time.

Date::Parse strptime parse the date into an array ( $ss, $mm, $hh, $day, $month, $year, $zone ). That allows the year to be converted back to a 4-digit year using:

```
if ( $year < 1000 ) { $year += 1900; }
```

The date is then passed into DateTime->new().

### Solution 2 (better)

Based on discussion with thanos on perlmonks, I explored using the Date::Manip module to parse datetimes. This simplified parsing variable inputs to as little as one line. It even handles 2-digit years correctly. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
say UnixDate( ParseDate($_), '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) for (@dates);
```

See example scripts and output on [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1209520).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another possible solution using module [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip.pod).

```
use Date::Manip;
use use feature 'say';

foreach my $datestr (@dates) {
    my $epochSecs = UnixDate($datestr,'%s');
    my $date = UnixDate( ParseDateString("epoch $epochSecs"), "%Y-%m-%d %T");
    say "Date value =  ".$datestr.", epoch = ".$epochSecs.", date = " .$date;
}
```

Hope this helps, BR.

Comment: Using Date::Manip simplified my code greatly (see my answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Epoch time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. The date your are trying to convert to epoch time is earlier than this.

Why are you using two different date-time libraries? If you want a DateTime object, use a DateTime module.

```
use DateTime::Format::DateParse qw( );

for my $dt_str (@dates) {
    my $dt = DateTime::Format::DateParse->parse_datetime($dt_str, $DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE)
       or die(...);

    ...
}
```

Produces:

```
1899-06-24 09:44:00 => 3799-06-24T09:44:00  <- doh!
1900-12-31 23:59:59 => 3800-12-31T23:59:59  <- doh!
1901-01-01 00:00:00 => 1901-01-01T00:00:00
1960-12-31 23:59:59 => 1960-12-31T23:59:59
1966-06-24 09:44:00 => 1966-06-24T09:44:00
1968-12-31 23:59:59 => 1968-12-31T23:59:59
1969-01-01 00:00:00 => 1969-01-01T00:00:00
1969-12-31 23:59:59 => 1969-12-31T23:59:59
1970-01-01 00:00:01 => 1970-01-01T00:00:01
2000-01-01 00:00:00 => 2000-01-01T00:00:00
2017-06-24 23:59:59 => 2017-06-24T23:59:59
2018-06-24 09:44:00 => 2018-06-24T09:44:00
2238-06-24 09:44:00 => 2238-06-24T09:44:00
2018-02-20 00:00:00 => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
20180220            => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
02/20/2018          => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
02/20/18            => 1918-02-20T00:00:00
2018-02-20          => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
```

Let's avoid DateParse entirely.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );
use List::MoreUtils            qw( first_result );

my @patterns = (
   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   '%Y-%m-%d',
   '%Y%m%d',
   '%m/%d/%Y',
   '%m/%d/%y',
);

my @formats =
   map {
      DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
         pattern   => $_,
         time_zone => $DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE,
         on_error  => 'undef',
      )
   }
      @patterns;

for my $dt_str (@dates) {
    my $dt = first_result { $_->parse_datetime($dt_str) } @formats
       or die(...);

    ...
}
```

Produces:

```
1899-06-24 09:44:00 => 1899-06-24T09:44:00
1900-12-31 23:59:59 => 1900-12-31T23:59:59
1901-01-01 00:00:00 => 1901-01-01T00:00:00
1960-12-31 23:59:59 => 1960-12-31T23:59:59
1966-06-24 09:44:00 => 1966-06-24T09:44:00
1968-12-31 23:59:59 => 1968-12-31T23:59:59
1969-01-01 00:00:00 => 1969-01-01T00:00:00
1969-12-31 23:59:59 => 1969-12-31T23:59:59
1970-01-01 00:00:01 => 1970-01-01T00:00:01
2000-01-01 00:00:00 => 2000-01-01T00:00:00
2017-06-24 23:59:59 => 2017-06-24T23:59:59
2018-06-24 09:44:00 => 2018-06-24T09:44:00
2238-06-24 09:44:00 => 2238-06-24T09:44:00
2018-02-20 00:00:00 => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
20180220            => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
02/20/2018          => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
02/20/18            => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
2018-02-20          => 2018-02-20T00:00:00
```

Comment: The OP needs to be able to handle dates in multiple formats supported by Date::Parse. The example code in the question is not great because all the dates are ISO 8601.

Comment: Here is an array of multiple formats I might receive: ````my @dates = (
    "2018-02-20 00:00:00",
    "20180220",
    "02/20/2018",
    "02/20/18",
    "2018-02-20"
);````